# Can I use keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true,y_pred) without training process?

Tags: keras, deep-learning, loss

I am new to Keras. I want to know the loss of certain instances. So I got the y_true and y_pred of these data instances. I want to call the loss function to calculate the loss but only get Tensor("Mean_5:0",shape=(),dtype=float32). How can I evaluate the value of the tensor? Is it similar to tensorflow by calling los.eval()?

y_pred is calcualted by:

```
y_pred = self.model.predict(x, batch_size=self.batch_size)
```

y_true is also an available list.

How to use binary_crossentropy()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had the answer.

```
from keras import backend
from keras.losses import binary_crossentropy
y_true = backend.variable(y_true)
y_pred = backend.variable(y_pred)
# calculate the average cross-entropy
mean_ce = backend.eval(binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred))
print('Average Cross Entropy: %.3f nats' % mean_ce)
```